# NetSuite SuiteTalk 2.0 address sublist defaultshipping and defaultbilling not being set

Tags: netsuite

I am having a heck of a time getting the `defaultshipping` and `defaultbilling` checks to be set when inserting a new customer record. I have included my code below and have tried several different things but for some reason on the first address that is inserted both `defaultshipping` and `defaultbilling` are set but the second address has nothing checked.

```
define([ 'N/record', 'N/runtime' ],

function(record, runtime) {

    function doPost(requestBody) {

        var custRec = record.create({
            type : record.Type.CUSTOMER,
            isDynamic : true
        });

        var addresses = [ 
               custBillAddr = {
                addr1 : '2100 S. Blah St.',
                addr2 : '',
                addressee : 'Test Person',
                city : 'Test Ville',
                defaultbilling : true,
                defaultshipping : false,
                state : 'IA',
                zip : '12345'
            }, custShipAddr = {
                addr1 : '5144 S. Test St.',
                addr2 : '',
                addressee : 'Tester Test',
                city : 'Test City',
                defaultbilling : false,
                defaultshipping : true,
                state : 'TX',
                zip : '54321'
            }];

        var curScript = runtime.getCurrentScript();

        var defEntity = curScript.getParameter({
            name : 'custscript_default_entity_status'
        });

        var defSub = curScript.getParameter({
            name : 'custscript_default_subsidary'
        });

        var custData = {
            accountnumber : '112233',
            companyname : 'Testing Company',
            email : 'Testing@example.com',
            entityid : '112233',
            entitystatus : defEntity,
            externalid : '123',
            subsidiary : defSub,
        };

        for ( var key in custData) {
            if (custData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                custRec.setValue({
                    fieldId : key,
                    value : custData[key]
                });
            }
        }

        /* create address sub lists here */
        custRec = upsertAddresses(custRec, addresses);

        var recordId = custRec.save({
            enableSourcing : false,
            ignoreMandatoryFields : false
        });

        return JSON.stringify(recordId);

    }

    function upsertAddresses(custRec, addresses) {
        for ( var address in addresses) {

            custRec.selectNewLine({ sublistId : 'addressbook' });

            var addList = custRec.getCurrentSublistSubrecord({ sublistId : 'addressbook', fieldId : 'addressbookaddress' });

            for ( var key in addresses[address]) {
                addList.setValue({ fieldId : key, value : addresses[address][key] });
            }
            custRec.commitLine({ sublistId : 'addressbook' });
        }

        return custRec;
    }


    return {
        post : doPost,
    };

});
```

In the addresses array of address objects I tried using:

```
defaultbilling : true
defaultbilling : 'T'
defaultbilling : 'Yes'
defaultbilling : 1
```

but none of them worked to set the field and I am not getting an error. Hoping someone here can tell me what I did wrong when trying to set those fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a very similar issue.  Turns out that the addressbook in 2.0 needs a subrecord of the sublist.  The code below is not exactly what you are asking for, but it should help you with what you need to do.  In mine I'm getting the values, where you just need to set them.  Hope this helps out.

```
define(['N/record','N/https','N/search'],function(record,https,search){
  function sendContactData(context){
    var contactNewRecord=context.newRecord;
    if(context.type=='create' || contactNewRecord.getValue('nluser')=='1234'){return;}
    var contactID=contactNewRecord.getValue('id');
    var contactObjectRecord=record.load({type:record.Type.CONTACT,id:contactID,isDynamic:true,});
    var shippingAddr1='';
    var shippingCity='';
    var shippingState='';
    var shippingZip='';
    var shippingCountry='';
    var numLines=contactNewRecord.getLineCount({sublistId:'addressbook'});
    if(numLines>0){
      for(var addressCount=0;addressCount<numLines;addressCount++){
        var addressShipping=contactNewRecord.getSublistValue({
          sublistId:'addressbook',
          fieldId:'defaultshipping',
          line:addressCount
        });
        if(addressShipping==true){break;}
      }
    }
    if(addressShipping==true){
      //Select the line set as the default shipping:
      contactObjectRecord.selectLine({sublistId:"addressbook",line:addressCount});
      var shippingAddressSubrecord=contactObjectRecord.getCurrentSublistSubrecord({sublistId:"addressbook",fieldId:"addressbookaddress"}); //Access the addressbookaddress subrecord:
      if(shippingAddressSubrecord){
        shippingAddr1=shippingAddressSubrecord.getValue({fieldId:'addr1'});
        shippingCity=shippingAddressSubrecord.getValue({fieldId:'city'});
        shippingState=shippingAddressSubrecord.getValue({fieldId:'state'});
        shippingZip=shippingAddressSubrecord.getValue({fieldId:'zip'});
        shippingCountry=shippingAddressSubrecord.getValue({fieldId:'country'});
      }
    }
  };  /* END sendContactData() */

  return{
    afterSubmit:sendContactData
  } /* END return block */
}); /* END define(['N/record'],function(record) */
```

Comment: I am afraid I don't see the difference between what you are doing and what I am doing. I am able to set all fields except for the checkboxes for some reason. Inside of my `upsertAddress` function I am getting the sublist subrecord of addressbook and looping over the address fields and setting them.

Comment: Nevermind I got it and it was thanks to your post. After looking at it further I realized what I was doing wrong. The address fields themselves are the sublist subrecord but the checkboxes are part of the sublist. So I was able to do `custRec.selectNewLine({ sublistId : 'addressbook' });
  custRec.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'addressbook', fieldId: 'defaultshipping', value: false });` and set the value of the checkboxes.

Comment: I think if maybe you updated your answer to reflect what I used I think it could be helpful to someone else looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having the same issue where I needed to pull the default shipping zip code beforeSubmit and set a custom field with that zip code. Big thanks to @w3bguy for getting me on the right path. if anyone needs to know how, here's the modified code.

```
    /**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(['N/record'],
    /**
 * @param{record} record
 */
    (record) => {

        /**
         * Defines the function definition that is executed before record is submitted.
         * @param {Object} scriptContext
         * @param {Record} scriptContext.newRecord - New record
         * @param {Record} scriptContext.oldRecord - Old record
         * @param {string} scriptContext.type - Trigger type; use values from the context.UserEventType enum
         * @since 2015.2
         */
        const beforeSubmit = (context) => {
            var contactNewRecord=context.newRecord;
            var currentShiptoZip = contactNewRecord.getValue({
              fieldId: 'custentity_shiptoZip'
          });
            if((context.type=='create' || context.type=='edit') && currentShiptoZip == ''){
            var numLines=contactNewRecord.getLineCount({sublistId:'addressbook'});
    if(numLines>0){
      for(var addressCount=0;addressCount<numLines;addressCount++){
        var addressShipping=contactNewRecord.getSublistValue({
          sublistId:'addressbook',
          fieldId:'defaultshipping',
          line:addressCount
        });
        if(addressShipping==true){break;}
      }
    }
        //Select the line set as the default shipping:
        var subrec = contactNewRecord.getSublistSubrecord({
          sublistId: 'addressbook',
          fieldId: 'addressbookaddress',
          line: addressCount
      });

      // Create a variable to initialize it to the
      // value of the subrecord's city field.
      var shippingZip = subrec.getValue({
          fieldId: 'zip'
      });
      log.debug({
        title: shippingZip
      });
        contactNewRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'custentity_shiptoZip',
            value: shippingZip
        });
      }
        }



        return {beforeSubmit}

    });
```